# Is it possible to run selenium 3.x tests with Firefox later than 52, having "marionette" capability set to false (NOT using GeckoDriver)?

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, webdriver, geckodriver

Having selenium 3.13.0 I cannot run tests against Firefox 60 ESR. On creating an instance of the FirefoxDriver it throws the timeout exception.

It worked fine with Firefox 52 ESR, until I updated to the 60 ESR. I suspect that Firefox 60 requires the GeckoDriver and is not compatible with the "legacy" approach which used driver built-in into the Selenium server.

So, the question:   is it possible to avoid using the GeckoDriver, working with Firefox 60?

Here's the example of code (options.setCapability("marionette", false))

```
private WebDriver createFirefoxDriver() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    // marionette = false to NOT use geckodriver
    options.setCapability("marionette", false);

    options.addPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/json, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, " +
                    "application/download, application/octet-stream");
    options.addPreference("browser.download.useToolkitUI", true);
    options.addPreference("dom.disable_window_flip", false);
    options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", Paths.get(EnvironmentProperties.get().sdaPathToTestData).toAbsolutePath().toString());

    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    return webDriver;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it is not possible. Last version you can use is Firefox 52.9, after that there is no support for Legacy driver, Firefox 60 ESR doesn't have the support for legacy driver.

It's really a sad news because I still find the problem with gecko in some places but legacy driver I have never find such an issue. The major one I missed out from legacy driver is visibility checking, I have actually raised the issue in geckodriver but still they have not added yet. Start using geckodriver which can't be equivalent to legacy driver but try to handle the missing part from your program.

My best advise is to use WATIR which is a wrapper around selenium ruby binding if you use WATIR you really don't have to bother about which driver you use because it handles everything from problem. There are some exception classes Chrome is not giving but firefox is offering ,in such a condition you may find some differences but apart from that there is no other differences.